# Can I still cash my check if the amount is written before the name of the payee?

Tags: paycheck

My boss wrote me out a check but accidentally wrote the dollar amount first before writing my name.  Is that a bad thing? Or can I still cash my check?

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? Do you mean above/to the left of? Is the information written in the wrong preprinted spaces?

Comment: What is actually written on the check, and where?

Answer (score 2):

It 100% depends on the bank, but as long as it is clear and doesn't look like someone tried to alter the check materially (like to a different person) it will probably be fine. There is no universal rule for the format of the check.